# Find last occurrence of specific value in a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I have a table that keeps scores from fantasy football league. The lowest scoring week is not included in the total.

I'm able to find the lowest score using the `=min function [=min(B2:R2)]`

I can find the first instance using the `=match function. [=MATCH(S2,B2:R2,0)]`

However I would like a formula that returns the latest occurrence of the lowest scoring week.

For example Portia lowest score is 8 the first occurrence is week 4 but I would like it to return the latest occurrence which is week 11

[image]

Comment: Define latest occurrence?

Comment: Latest occurrence / last occurrence would be the most recent. If there are more than one occurrence of the lowest score, I would like the formula to return the most recent. For Portia is would be week 11, Phoebe week 4, Anastasia week 11.

Comment: `=INDEX(1:1,1,MAX(COLUMN(B2:R2)*(B2:R2=MIN(B2:R2))))` entered as an array formula (using Ctrl-Shift-Enter)

Comment: Not sure the way you input the values. Are you inserting the values manually? If you are inserting through some text fields, you can add a timestamp on when you make the changes. Then just return the field with the latest time stamp.

Answer (score 17):

You can also do this using `LOOKUP` function and avoiding array formulas, e.g. assuming `S2` has the minimum value you can get the last week with that value with this formula in `T2` copied down

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(B2:R2=S2),B$1:R$1)`

This works because `(B2:R2=S2)` returns an array of `TRUE/FALSE` values, and then dividing 1 by that array gives you an array of `1`s or `#DIV/0!` errors. When you use `2` as the **lookup value** on that array it won't find any `2`s so will therefore match with the **last** number (the last 1) in the array. That corresponds to the last week with your smallest value so using the top row as the "return vector" means that the formula returns the corresponding week number as required

Comment: Almost 4 years later and this is exactly what I was looking for, plus I learned the 1/(<range>=<value>) technique as a bonus. :-) Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use an Array Formula to achieve this.  The following will return the "highest" lowest value if you are using columns B:R as the data columns and column T as the **Low Week** column.  You need to enter this as an array (CSE) formula by copying and pasting it into cell T2 and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$R$1,1,SMALL(IF(B2:R2=MIN(B2:R2),COLUMN(B2:R2),FALSE),COUNTIF(B2:R2,MIN(B2:R2)))),"")
```

### Explanation

First, the `COUNTIF(B2:R2,MIN(B2:R2))` will count the number of times the minimum value occurs.  This is needed because a simple`MIN(B2:R2)` will only grab the *first* minimum value, not the nth minimum value.

Next, the `IF(B2:R2=MIN(B2:R2),COLUMN(B2:R2),FALSE)` is the actual array formula part of the equation (the reason why you need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).  It will only return the references for when you have a minimum and returning `FALSE` for all other entries greater than the minimum.  Now, you have an array of only the column numbers the smallest values in the dataset.

Then, the `SMALL(IF(B2:R2=MIN(B2:R2),COLUMN(B2:R2),FALSE),COUNTIF(B2:R2,MIN(B2:R2)))` will take the column numbers of the smallest values and find the latest occurrence of this, which comes from the `COUNTIF(B2:R2,MIN(B2:R2))` code.

Now that the last smallest occurrences' column number is know, you can use the `INDEX` function to find the value in the first row `INDEX($A$1:$R$1,1`.

Finally, the `IFERROR` will display the **Low Week** row if the `SMALL` function finds a match, otherwise it will display a blank cell.  This could be used to copy this array formula further down the page for rows that you don't yet have users for.

### Result

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thank you Michael. Your solution works and you have given me a lot to read up on. I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.