# Replacing text on a spreedSheet according to match text x Rows above it

Tags: excel, vba

Good day people, this is my first post here. I'm trying to understand what's the logic for this issue i want to fix:

I have a spreedsheet with the sales of clients, each one with a different name. Every Client has under its name a date and to the right the amount of money sold that day. Then after the last day registered there's the word "Total"  I need to change every "Total" so that it says "Total Client A" . "Total Client B", ETC, according to which client the "total" belongs to . Example

- Client 1
- DATE .............Value
- 2016-05-01 ...  $2.500
- 2016-05-02  ... $2.350
- 2016-05-03 ...  $3.450
- Total..............$8.300
- Client 2
- DATE............Value
- 2016-05-01.. $2.000
- 2016-05-02...$2.600
- 2016-05-03...$2.400
- Total..............$7.000

etc etc. So the idea is to have in the above example instead of "Total", Total Client 1, Total Client 2, etc.

CLIENT X, can be any name. It doesn't follow  a logic. The only constant is that underneath it there's the cell "DATE"

The file changes each day (adding a new Date with it's respective sale, and the reprocessed total) and i need to process the file daily. The idea is each day to have the file say "Total Client x ",(instead of just "Total") so i can use that file to another process that i have.

Thanks a lot for any help,

Comment: You could do it with array formula, something like this `=IF(NOT(ISNUMBER($A$1:$A10)),ROW($A$1:$A10))`  then access the LARGE(x,1) value.  The array will return {1,2,6,7,8} so you'll need to add extra criteria like <>"date"  I'll try and do an answer, but about to leave work

Comment: something like `="TOTAL FOR :" & INDEX($A$1:$A13,MAX(IF(NOT(ISNUMBER($A$1:$A13)*($A$1:$A13<>"")),ROW($B$1:$B13))),1)`  where the data in your post is in columns A & B

Answer (score 0):

Using an array formula, you can add extra criteria also, to tweak.

`="TOTAL FOR :" & INDEX($A$1:$A13,MAX(IF(NOT(ISNUMBER($A$1:$A13)*($A$1:$A13<>"")),ROW($B$1:$B13)))‌​,1)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, i'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

This uses one of my favorite tricks given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27390134/1693085).

Assuming your data starts in column A with the first value in `A1`, and, then assuming your first total was in cell, say `A10` (I just need an address to show you what it would look like), you could use the following formula for your total in A10:

```
="Total " & LOOKUP(2, 1/($A$2:A9="Date"), $A$1:A8)
```

And you can then copy and paste that exact formula into any other total cell in Excel.

Basically, it says the following:

- Start with the word "Total "
- Look in cells `A2` till the cell directly above me and find the last occurrence of the word "Date" (`LOOKUP(2, 1/($A$2:A9="Date"), ...)` - See the link above to explain why this works)
- Lookup the values of the cells directly above them to know what to bring in (`LOOKUP(... ,$A$1:A8)`).

Hope that makes sense and does the trick!

Comment: Thanks a lot!. I'll try this one too.