# How to combine Pivot Tables and also create custom formula in its fields - Excel 2016

Tags: pivot-table, data-analysis, excel-2016, pivot-chart

I am preparing a **Material Tracking System** for my Paper Corrugated Fibreboard Production Unit using MS Excel 2016 for Windows. Basically, I will be entering the material details that are added to the Stock and as and when those materials are used I make an entry accordingly. I am using Pivot Tables and Charts to analyse my data.

Example: Let's consider the major raw material i.e. **Paper Rolls**. I have prepared a workbook [Roll Stock](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3Zjp8yTk-eLYklqd3hrUVF0NzA) with all necessary data, tables and charts. I have created another workbook [Roll Log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3Zjp8yTk-eLS19GdVZmZEI2aEU) in which I will be entering the details with actions **Issued** and **Returned** along with the **Weight** of the Roll when the it is taken out or returned back to the store respectively. I am using unique numbers to identify each Roll (kindly have a look at the files before proceeding further).

**The Problem:**

1. In order to track usage details in Roll Log's Pivot table, I should be able to perform some simple validations like whether the weight of a particular roll when **Issued** by the operator is greater than when its been **Returned**, whether the same roll is **Returned** before its **Issued** again on the same/different date ....etc. Is it possible in Excel ?
2. Combining Data from **Roll Stock** and **Roll Log**:

   a. Say Roll **R000001** weighed 789kg when bought from the vendor on 7-Oct-2016. An entry with the same details was made in the workbook **Roll Stock**.

   b. **R000001** was issued to an operator on 8-Oct-2016 and an entry with the same details was made in the workbook **Roll Log** with **Action** as **Issued**.

   c. The operator used 560kg and **Returned** it to the Stores on 9-Oct-2016 and a corresponding entry was made in the log again with **Action** as **Returned**. All of this data is captured in the **Roll Log**'s pivot.

Now how can I use this value to reduce the quantity dynamically in the **Roll Stock**'s pivot so that every time I see the **Dashboard** in **Roll Stock**, it gives me the latest available stock. **I would prefer not to use VBA since it slows down my workbooks drastically**

PS: This is just a temporary system and I will be going for an ERP soon. But I would be really thankful if someone can help me get this thing going as per my expectation. Please feel free to suggest any kind of improvements.

Answer (score 0):

**On question 2:** Your workbooks do not show any connection between `Action (Issued/Returned)` in the Roll Log and `Available Quantity` in the Roll Stock. I will assume this is to be the case.

The option that jumps out at me is to use a formula for the `Available Quantity` in the Roll Stock. The formula should look at the last `Quantity` for the roll in the Roll Log.

Using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388915/find-last-occurrence-of-specific-value-in-a-row) to find the last occurrence of a value in a column, I would recommend the following formula ...

`=IF(ISNA(LOOKUP(2,1/('Roll Log.xlsx'!T_Roll_Log[Roll Number]=[@[Roll Number]]),'Roll Log.xlsx'!T_Roll_Log[Quantity (kg)])),[@[Received Qty (kg)]],LOOKUP(2,1/('Roll Log.xlsx'!T_Roll_Log[Roll Number]=[@[Roll Number]]),'Roll Log.xlsx'!T_Roll_Log[Quantity (kg)]))`

If the Lookup function returns NA (that is, the roll does not appear in the Roll Log), then use the `Received Qty`. Otherwise, use the last value that appears for that roll in the Roll Log.

Then refresh your pivot table.

**On question 1:** I would add a column to your Roll Log table that both checks that upon return, the previous action for a roll was "Issued", and that calculates the quantity used.

The formula would look like the following ...

`=IF([@Action]="Returned",IF(LOOKUP(2,1/($D$4:$D5=[@[Roll Number]]),[Action])="Issued",LOOKUP(2,1/($D$4:$D5=[@[Roll Number]]),[Quantity (kg)]-[@[Quantity (kg)]]),"MISHANDLED"),"")`

... and would provide results like this ...

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. But I'm still not able to get what I exactly want. In case of Question 1 the solution you have provided almost serves the purpose. But I want to check if the nth Action and the (n-1)th Action for a particular Roll are the same i.e. "Issued" & then "Issued" again or "Returned" and "Returned" again consecutively. Hope its not too much to ask from Excel !!!